# Verb for "adjusting" glasses?

Tags: verbs

I searched jisho and found `整える` but doing a google search for

> メガネを整える

came up with practically no results so I feel that it's not the appropriate verb.

> メガネを繕う

came up with more hits, is that the right one?

Comment: We're talking about [this](https://www.animeclick.it/prove/upload/img/News38039.gif), right?

Comment: ya, putting them back up higher on your nose

Comment: メガネを繕う sounds as if the glasses were broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would probably say...

> ずり[落]{お}ちたメガネをかけ[直]{なお}す
>   ずり落ちたメガネ（の位置）を[直]{なお}す
>   ずり落ちたメガネを｛[上]{あ}げる / （指で）[押]{お}し上げる｝

Comment: And so would I as a glass-wearing native Japanese-speaker.

Answer (score 4):

Let me add a couple of phrases: 眼鏡を上げる、眼鏡を押し上げる、and 眼鏡クイッ. The first two are fairly common.

The last one is a slangy (a bit otaku) phrase to describe the motion. Not really useful in normal conversion, but you can use it as 眼鏡をクイッと(かけ)直す仕草 and everyone should understand.

Comment: `上げ押し上げる` ← 「上げ」が二回出てきますけど、書き間違ってたりしません？

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。あまり携帯から書き込みしないものて…

Answer (score 2):

> 眼鏡を押し上げる. Pushing up one's glasses.

Credit to @siikamiika.

Comment: ah nice thanks, not sure how I forgot about 調整する, lots of relevant google hits

Comment: The example sentence is about telescopes so I'm not sure if it applies to what OP is looking for but maybe 「眼鏡を押し上げる」= the act of pushing up your glasses and 「眼鏡の位置を調整する」= adjust the position of your glasses

Comment: @siikamiika yours sounds more accurate, do you want to put your answer up instead? I can take mine down.

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone I'm not fully confident in those but if you want to check if they are actually used you can add them to your answer

Comment: Most native speakers would think of other actions upon hearing the phrase 「眼鏡を調整する」.  They would think of adjusting some part of the glasses using **tools** like a little screw driver.  「調整」 would be too big a word for what we are talking about here.